# CLR creating a new function with different arguments for my imported C++ code

Tags: c#, c++, clr, pinvoke

```
using namespace ParasolidAssembly;

AssemblyClass::AssemblyClass() {
    bool startParasolid();
    bool stopParasolid();
};
void AssemblyClass::Perform(string FileName) {
    bool bScale = true;

    // Var
    PK_ERROR_t error;
    int nParts, nGeoms;
```

This is the original function that is defined in the C++ code and imported into the C# application using the namespace Parasolidassembly. But not able to use the Perform function with just string argument as a different definition for the function is created, like...

```
amespace ParasolidAssembly
{
public class AssemblyClass : IDisposable
{
public AssemblyClass();

public override sealed void Dispose();
protected virtual void Dispose(bool A_0);
public void Perform(std.basic_string_char,std::char_traits_char_,std::allocator_char_ _* FileName);
public bool startParasolid();
public bool stopParasolid();
}
}
```

This is in a file which is named Assemblyclass(from metadata) , giving rise to error 
Error   144 The best overloaded method match for 'ParasolidAssembly.AssemblyClass.Perform(std.basic_string,std::allocator >*)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\ranjith\Desktop\ifab_assembly\GraphSynthConsole\AssemblySearch1.cs 34

Comment: how is the code 'imported' into c#?

Comment: The .dll from the c++ code is added to the debug folder in the project and the namespace parasolidassembly is being used.

Comment: What does the line where you're calling it look like?

Comment: var CAD2Graph = new AssemblyClass();
CAD2Graph.Perform(settings.DefaultSeedFileName);

Comment: Also added the dll file from the C++ code as a reference to the C# project.

Comment: is this  a 'normal' c++ DLL or a managed c++ (or whatever its called now)? YOu cannot simply call normal c++ code from c#, you need to use pinvoke